# How to improve understanding of long sentences in prose?

Tags: learning, reading

What are some efficient, methodical, productive ways to improve the skill and speed of interpreting, parsing, and reading long prosaic sentences? I refer not only to legalese or legal language, but also any complx sentence written in modern English prose. For instance, are there basics, fundaments, or prerequisites about sentences that I should  self-learn?

Thus far on ELL, I question anew every long sentence that confuses me, but want to transcend this approach 'by chance', which feels like a wastefully haphazard, torturous crawl of piecemeal creeps that hobble too narrowly to reach, even the rungs towards, the apex of sentential comprehension sought.

Comment: Love your last scentence...

Comment: So on a more serious note: Do you have a basic understanding of the elements of sentences? (I strongly suppose so...)

Comment: Many of the passages you have asked about have been rather tortuous. Do you have the same problems with a Henry James novel? His sentences are long, but lucid. http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2833/2833-h/2833-h.htm#link2HCH0001

Comment: If you could write that last sentence, I doubt you'll face any problems with understanding one!

Comment: "Occam's secateurs" ;-)

Comment: @Stephie: "Scentence" is brilliant :-)

Comment: @Stephie: Thank you. I should clarify that my last para is intended to be ironic. What does 'scentence' imply though? Are you implying that my sentence is saturated with meaningless floridity (I chose 'floridity' because you used 'scent', which flowers usually transmit)?

Comment: @Stephie: About my issue more seriously, I think so. Do you mean subject + predicate or subject + verb + object? How can I advance further?

Comment: @Faisal Thanks, but I was really trying to be ironic. Please see my other questions in which I simply (contend to) struggle with them!

Comment: @TRomano Sorry about the torture. Are you referring to my legal passages? If so, how can I improve, because they are from common law books? About Henry James: Would you please cite what you think is the longest and hardest sentence in that book? I started to read the beginning and didn't see such a sentence.

Comment: You should try submitting that last sentence to the Bulwer-Lytton Fiction Contest next year. http://www.bulwer-lytton.com/

Comment: @AdamHaun Really? I was only being ironic. Or are you also being ironic?

Comment: I was mostly serious. I understood your intent and I think the sentence worked well.

Comment: If you're not having any troubles with the first three paragraphs of that Henry James novel, then you need to refine your question, for it isn't the length or even the syntactic complexity of the sentences that is causing your troubles; rather your trouble comes from the combination of jargon, abstraction, archaisms, and peculiar use of prepositions that are typical of much legal writing. It's quite common that very competent native speakers have to puzzle out the meaning of a legal text.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Bonjour Presentiment! Can you give us a paragraph with some long sentences. It will help to illustrate a useful answer with! Thanks :)

Comment: @AdamHaun Thank you then. I'll read more about that contest, which I hadn't known about until your kind suggestion!

Comment: @Araucaria Hello again! I've changed my name temporarily to promote Law, but will revert later. I'll be happy to update this question with such a para, but please allow me some time for this because I have to light upon a new one (so I remain sadly on this 'approach by chance').

Comment: @TRomano Thank you. To confirm the need for refinement, would you please suggest numerous pieces of non-legal prose that you consider the hardest, densest? I'll try to read and opine on them.

Comment: "Dense prose" is an oxymoron, in my book. Finish that Henry James novel while you're at it.

Comment: I could suggest William Faulkner. A book of his short stories is [downloadable](https://archive.org/details/collectedstories030393mbp). His novel *As I lay dying* is difficult. But I wonder, do you want to become a lawyer or something? I think **reading for pleasure** is a great way to improve comprehension. If you are slogging through books just for their [difficulty](http://www.publishersweekly.com/pw/by-topic/industry-news/tip-sheet/article/53409-the-top-10-most-difficult-books.html), what is the point?

Comment: @CarSmack Thanks, I'll try to read it. I'm extremely interested in law, so that's why I've been reading these law books and not because of their difficulty. Yet I agree that I should read other genres for pleasure.

Comment: If you do read that short story collection, good luck with the second sentence of the first story. I still haven't figured it out, but sometimes an exact meaning is unknown until one has read the whole story. In general, reading in a 2nd language is done much like you read in your 1st language. Think about how you do what you ask while reading in your native language.

Comment: Parse the sentences into their various phrases. Find the noun and verb, and then ask how does every other phrase work in this sentence. But I think you've already been doing that.

Comment: [This](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/serious-reading-takes-a-hit-from-online-scanning-and-skimming-researchers-say/2014/04/06/088028d2-b5d2-11e3-b899-20667de76985_story.html?wpmk=MK0000202) suggests a little reading: ... their students are having trouble reading the classics.

“They cannot read ‘Middlemarch.’ They cannot read William James or Henry James,” Wolf said. “I can’t tell you how many people have written to me about this phenomenon. The students no longer will or are perhaps incapable of dealing with the convoluted syntax and construction of George Eliot and Henry James.”

Comment: @Araucaria I managed to find a harder passage, but please ignore these if they don't merit your or anyone's time to understand: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/22080, http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/22077, http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/22075. Fortunately, http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/22079 is easier.

Answer (score 6):

### 1. Rewrite other people’s short sentences

Take some text with short sentences and rewrite it so it says everything in one sentence.

Children's books are a good source of short sentences. (Well-known children's books are excellent ways to learn a language generally, because they provide the mental "landmarks" that shaped most natives' earliest understanding of the written language.) Here's the first page of *Curious George*:

> One day George saw a man.
>
> He had on a large yellow straw hat.
>
> The man saw George too.
>
> “What a nice little monkey,” he thought.
>
> “I would like to take him home with me.”
>
> He put his hat on the ground
>
> and, of course, George was curious.
>
> He came down from the tree
>
> to look at the large yellow hat.

Rewriting in long, “adult” sentences, here’s what I come up with:

> One day, George and a man wearing a large, yellow, straw hat saw each other, George in his tree and the man on the ground. The man, hoping to take George home with him, put his hat on the ground, arousing George's curiosity—an easy thing to do, George being naturally curious—and George came down from the tree to inspect it.

No two people would rewrite it the same way, of course. This suggests another thing you can do: get together with someone else, rewrite the same short text with long sentences, and compare your results. You'll each see how the other person exploits grammatical resources of English that you're not as aware of or accustomed to.

### 2. Read and write poems

Reading poetry will stretch your mastery of grammar quite a bit. A good one to start with is [*If—*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_(Rudyard_Kipling)#Text) by Rudyard Kipling. It's basically one huge sentence. It's also very well-known: famous poetry, like children's books and nursery rhymes, gives you the same "language landmarks" that native speakers have. It also introduces you to the common wisdom of the culture.

Here's a sample:

> If you can make a heap of all your winnings
>
> And risk it on one turn of pitch-and-toss,
>
> And lose, and start again at your beginnings
>
> And never breathe a word about your loss;

It goes on for a long time with many **if**s like this before it finally reaches its conclusion in the last two lines of the poem. To understand the sentence fragment above, here are some things that you have to follow: **make a heap of** means to gather many things into a big pile; **it** refers to the **heap**; **risk it** means to bet it; **one turn** means a single round of a game; **pitch-and-toss** is a gambling game; **your loss** refers to the event of losing the bet or to everything that you lost (it doesn’t matter); and the events follow this sequence: earning a lot of wealth, betting it all at once, losing the bet, starting from poverty again and accumulating new wealth (not from gambling, probably from work)—while never complaining or commiserating. The whole thing is governed by **can**: the events didn't happen and don't need to happen. It's all just a clause describing the *ability* to go through all that and not complain; *if* you have that ability, then…well, you have to keep reading to find out the consequence.

It's okay if you have to read each sentence in a poem many times before you fully understand it. It's poetry. It packs a lot of meaning into relatively few words, and it uses language in extraordinary ways, so it *is* harder to understand than prose. Native speakers usually need several readings to understand it, too.

But if you really want to master prose, *write* poetry. This is especially true for mastering the more-complex grammar of long sentences. In poetry, you push grammar to its limits—far beyond the limits of prose. Consequently, when you go back to prose, you find it much easier. You see that prose barely uses the grammatical resources of English at all.

Poetry *is* hard to write, and it's not for beginners. Even when you have a large-enough vocabulary to think of many ways to say the same thing, you still have to be willing to put up with a lot of frustration as you search for ways to meet the constraints of the form. If you write a few couplets and a few quatrains, you've done well. That alone will increase your command of grammar.

If you take this approach, you must write traditional verse that rhymes and scans, not free verse. Sticking strictly to the form provides the pressure to come up with interesting sentences and forms of expression. Within the limits of the form, you try to be as clear as you can, even as the form pushes you to express things in unusual ways and draw upon unusual syntax. It's not enough to *just* follow the form, of course; the poem must communicate clearly.

Comment: Excellent suggestions! I would suggest epic poetry as a bridge from prose. Epic poetry is less abstract and more narrative-focused than a lot of standalone poetry, but still features long, complex sentences. Try the Fitzgerald translation of Homer's Odyssey. There are some previews here:

http://www.nexuslearning.net/books/holt_elementsoflit-3/collection%2014/The%20Odyssey%20The%20Wandering%20p1.htm

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to mentally parenthetize complicated noun-phrases and relative clauses - perhaps even replacing the former with appropriate pronouns to help you sort things out conceptually.  If you haven't already done so, read [the Wikipedia article on Noun phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) - I think it can offer some genuine assistance in this area.