# How to improve in writing? My comprehension abilities are fairly good.

Tags: writing

I've been on the internet for quite a while now, I can safely say. I've come across countless of interesting threads from sites like Quora, Reddit, or here. I've also encountered many users who are really good in their English, judging from how they present their opinions or questions.

This is one of the examples (first answer by Ben Kovitz or the question by Canada Area 51 Proposal, they display abilities of good writing)

[How to overcome sequences of negative words which still cripple my comprehension?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51324/how-to-overcome-sequences-of-negative-words-which-still-cripple-my-comprehension?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In general, I can grasp what they're trying to say. But, when in comes to writing, I just can't. I have many ideas, in fact, great ideas. But, the problem is that I can't put them all in sentences and paragraphs coherently, let alone writing good essays.

I would like to write very naturally and fluently like how people on the internet do.

Comment: I think your writing in general is fine. So I think, maybe you can improve this question by adding what you can see in those writing examples you think are good, or even great, but not in yours.

Comment: A lot of people find precis a useful way of honing their writing skills. Take a 500 word article and cut it down to 100 words. It makes you think really hard about what is important and what's the best way to say something concisely.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, goodness. English is my mother tongue. I comprehend it very well and write it fairly well, too. I also understand French pretty well.

When I'm writing English, I ask myself questions like, "What is the best way to say this, out of many options?" When I'm trying to write French, my questions are more along the lines of, "Do I know any way of saying this, or if I know of more than one, do I even know, for certain, which one is better?"

The difference is that I have read thousands of books in English and have spoken it almost every day of my life. I think if you get to the point where you feel like you have many options about exactly how you want to say something in English, and you can understand the nuances between your many options, you will probably also be at a point where you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest keeping your sentences simple. Do not worry about adding any unnecessary words (fantastic, gorgeous, weighty), unless that is why you are commenting. ("Did you enjoy the scenery?" "Yes, the waterfalls were gorgeous there.")

Precise language is always good. If you know the word **hemoglobin** and you are among others that do, saying red blood cells makes no sense and not only because it is not accurate.

The other things to try are:

- Keep reading. The more you read, the more you can understand why another  writer might have chosen to 'put it that way'.
- Keep writing. There are tons of sites that explain exercises and truthfully, the more you exercise anything, the better likely you are to improve.

I'd suggest you start by editing your question. There are at least two areas that could use improvement, and yes, I understood you perfectly.

One of the best pieces of advice came to me via my author husband, who was told by the great Asimov -- to 'just write it'.  Asimov was a master crafter in simple, straightforward language and simply 'telling the story'.

You could also try book reporting. You read something and write about the story. Your exercise might be 500 words or 2000, that is up to you. This is an exercise and  not for publishing.

There is a Writer's Stack Exchange. I tried but did not find them particularly helpful, but you might. You need to find a group that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To write well requires re-writing. First, you write or sketch what you initially think you want to say. And then you revise, perhaps several times, until it says what you finally want to say exactly, grammatically, and persuasively.

Your example of a good answer is well chosen, but it was not dashed off in a few minutes. Writing well is work, often satisfying, but requiring time, patience, and concentration.

One habit I have found useful is to take a break after I think I have a final draft and then, after a delay, do one more re-write. How long a delay? If it is a fairly casual email, time enough to go downstairs to get a fresh cup of coffee. If it is a complex and important document not due today, the next morning.