# How can I instantly simplify 'The Opposition refused leave for the withdrawal of a motion to annul an Order revoking the embargo'?

Tags: multiple-negation

Source: Rebecca Gowers. [*Plain Words* (2014 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plain-Words-Rebecca-Gowers/dp/0241960347). p. 186 Middle.

> Here 
>   are two more examples of sentences that have to be unravelled before 
>   they yield any meaning.
>
> > [1.] The Opposition refused leave for the withdrawal of a motion to 
> >     annul an Order revoking the embargo on the importation of cut glass.

2. How could've I understood the sentence overhead more hurriedly, and not spend [15 minutes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/51324/8712) rewriting?
3. Can 1 be rewritten more precisely and reliability? Mine forsakes details.

1 can be streamlined to:

> 4. Opposition `refused leave for the withdrawal of` a motion to annul  an Order revoking the embargo [...].

'refuse leave for the withdrawal of' can be regarded as 'uphold'.  So 2 can be simplified to:

> 3. Opposition `upheld` a motion to annul an Order revoking the embargo.

Upholding a motion to do X, signifies upholding X. So 3 ⇒:

> 4. Opposition upheld annulling an Order revoking the embargo.

You'd uphold to annul X only if you scorn X. So 4 ⇒:

> 5. Opposition scorns an Order revoking the embargo. QED.

Comment: Are you thinking of this as "(The Opposition refused leave) (for the withdrawal of a motion) (to annul an Order revoking the embargo) (on the importation of cut glass)."? It might be more useful to point out which part is unclear, rather than try to rewrite it.

Comment: @user3169 I didn't decompose the sentence explicitly like you, but my mind probably did. Yet the decomposition doesn't help, because I couldn't unravel the first 3 parentheses in my mind?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of [*leave*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/leave): "*noun*
1. permission to do something - *he was granted **leave** to speak*"? The "to do something" is the "withdrawal of a motion". The rest just describes the motion.

Comment: @user316 Yes. I do understand that.